# how to use Ace_Scroll after ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll

I'm using Ace Admin Template.

I'm appending some contents to a div with id `#Mydiv`and using ace-scroll for that same div (`#Mydiv`). When I append contents to the div, ace-scroll does not work and doesn't detect the new height:

```
var out = '';
var dv = $('#Mydiv');
$.ajax({
   url:  url,
   type: 'POST',
   data:{pg:pg},
   error: function() {
     return;
   },
   dataType: 'html',

   success: function(data) {
     if(data.trim() !=='ERROR'){
       out = data.trim();   
       dv.append(out);
     }
   },

   complete:function(v){
     /////////NOT WORK//////////////////
     dv.ace_scroll({inline_style:true,size: 200,observeContent:true, mouseWheelLock: true});
   }  

});
```

Comment: did u get any solution of this??I am facing same problem..

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, it turns out that applying the scroll on the outer div was causing the problem. In your case, applying scroll on 'MyDiv' is the issue. Instead of applying scroll on 'MyDiv', you should have a div in the html returned from the ajax call, and apply scroll on that div.

```js
var out = '';
var dv = $('#Mydiv');
$.ajax({
   url:  url,
   type: 'POST',
   data:{pg:pg},
   error: function() {
     return;
   },
   dataType: 'html',

   success: function(data) {
     if(data.trim() !=='ERROR'){
       //Here the html in data.trim() should have an enclosing div like <div id = 'MyScrollDiv'> ...content... </div>
       out = data.trim();  
       
       dv.append(out);
     }
   },

   complete:function(v){
     /////////NOT WORK//////////////////
     
     //Don't apply scroll on dv
     //dv.ace_scroll({inline_style:true,size: 200,observeContent:true, mouseWheelLock: true});
     
     //Apply scroll on the inner div
     $('#MyScrollDiv').ace_scroll({inline_style:true,size: 200,observeContent:true, mouseWheelLock: true});
   }  

});
```